# Web Api 2 BaseController

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have controller

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
   [HttpGet]
   public string Test()
   {
      return "test";
   }
}
```

with

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(new CustomDirectRouteProvider());

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
public class CustomDirectRouteProvider : DefaultDirectRouteProvider
{
    protected override IReadOnlyList<IDirectRouteFactory>
    GetActionRouteFactories(HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<IDirectRouteFactory>
        (inherit: true);
    }
}
```

and it works like it should, but if I make it like

```
public class TestController : ApiControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet]
   public string Test()
   {
      return "test";
   }
}

public class ApiControllerBase : ApiController
{
}
```

I get 404 No type was found that matches the controller named 'Test'.

What am I doing wrong? I added the CustumRouteProvider even thought I think it's only used in annotations, but I tried that as well and no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please create an example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by example? This code was added to an existing MVC 4 application and problem is probably somewhere in that old code but I can't think of anything that would cause this problem

Comment: This exact code works for me in WebAPI 2.

Comment: I tried it in new project and it is working but it isn't working in the situation I described in comment above. One more thing to note is that this controller is inside an area and base controller is inside another project but that shouldn't matter. Can't think of anything else to tell you

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that ApiControllerBase was inside another project, even though that project had all references and compiled normally. Wierd.